# How to localize flow documents

Tags: wpf, localization, flowdocument

I want to realize context help for application View based on flow documents. For example, user presses Ctrl+F1 and context help about current View appears over this View. The help content must must be localized.

In window markup can looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="UdkppReports.Window2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window2" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <ContentControl x:Name="View"/>
    <ContentControl x:Name="Help" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentView.HelpContent}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

View.HelpContent property is the instance of a UserControl with embedded FlowDocumentScrollViewer. In non-localized application for each View class I will create one HelpContent class. What about for localized application?

One and only idea is present now - for each View class must be created as many HelpContent classes as many cultures application supports. For example, for SomeView class I have:

- SomeViewHelp class (default)
- SomeViewHelp_fr class
- SomeViewHelp_it class
- and so on

and in custom SomeView.LoadHelp command (or custom Loadhelp event or elsewhere) I need to dynamically determine name of the help class such as

```
string lang = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
string helpClassShortName = "SomeView_" + lang;
```

and further get the full class name, try to dynamically create instance of the help class and assign View.HelpContent property to this instance. This should work, but may be a standard approach to flow document localization exists?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try LocBaml tool for localization? Every xaml element supports x:Uid attribute, so you can use [this solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746621.aspx). Also there is an article about localization in MS Exam 70-502 Training Kit.

Comment: I don't try to use LocBAML because my own idea described in first message is seems to be quite appropriate the task.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way to do this is to use [WPF Localization Extension](http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com).
Take a look on discussion about flow document support with author of this library [click me](http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/discussions/448805)